# How to set 'compileDebugKotlin' task target to Java 17

Tags: react-native, android-studio, gradle, expo, hybrid-mobile-app

I upgraded my react-native project from expo 48 to 50 and Gradle wrapper to `8.7` after resolving some other issues I am stuck on this issue:
`Execution failed for task ':expo-permissions:compileDebugKotlin'.

> 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 17) and 'compileDebugKotlin' task (current target is 11) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.

Things I tried:

- Using Java toolchain (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle-configure-project.html#gradle-java-toolchains-support)
- Adding different plugins including `org.gradle.toolchains.foojay-resolver-convention`
- Adding `compatibilityOptions` and `kotlin` and `kotlinOptions` blocks with hardCoded Java version and `jvmToolchain(17)`
- Updating the Java version to 17 for gradle **Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle -> Gradle JDK**

and many other things but nothing seems to help.